# Applet without JMF installation at client side

Tags: java, applet, jmf

I am trying developing an applet which transmits audio and video. But I found a big problem that I have to make every client install the JMF, however the clients hope there is no software to be installed locally.

Is there any possibility to run the applet without JMF installation on the client side ?

Anyone can help on this matter

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_for_Java

With this users would not have to download anything. There is still an underlying dependency as the user will have to have Quicktime locally installed but thats a much more reasonable sell.

Comment: i want to do this without installing anything like quicktime or jmf in client side

Comment: error loks like this                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.ControllerListener
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 24 more
but class i have added "http://--server--/avapps/app/javax/media/ControllerListener.class"   class is present in this location

Comment: i doing in such a way that this class can be obtained from "s_my_jmf.jar" which i have added as a library,

Comment: If this is a question about using JMF then you should ask it in a new thread.